# save log into a file for different batchs

Tags: logging, slf4j, logback

I have 2 batch and i need to save hibernate and spring logs into separate files when i run them separately

So i have a logback configuration like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<configuration>

    <!-- Batch 1 -->

    <appender name="BatchALogToFile" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${logback.root.path}/batchA.log</file>
        <encoder>
            <charset>UTF-8</charset>
            <pattern>[%d{dd/MM/yyyy : HH:mm:ss}] %m%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
            <minIndex>1</minIndex>
            <maxIndex>30</maxIndex>
            <fileNamePattern>${logback.root.path}/batchA.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <triggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
            <MaxFileSize>20MB</MaxFileSize>
        </triggeringPolicy>
    </appender>

    <logger name="BatchALogger" additivity="false">
        <level value="DEBUG" />
        <appender-ref ref="BatchALogToFile" />
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </logger>

    <!-- End Batch1 -->


    <!-- Batch2 -->

    <appender name="BatchBLogToFile" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>${logback.root.path}/batchB.log</file>
        <encoder>
            <charset>UTF-8</charset>
            <pattern>[%d{dd/MM/yyyy : HH:mm:ss}] %m%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.FixedWindowRollingPolicy">
            <minIndex>1</minIndex>
            <maxIndex>30</maxIndex>
            <fileNamePattern>${logback.root.path}/batchB.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <triggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy">
            <MaxFileSize>20MB</MaxFileSize>
        </triggeringPolicy>
    </appender>

    <logger name="BatchBLogger" additivity="false">
        <level value="DEBUG" />
        <appender-ref ref="BatchBLogToFile" />
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </logger>

    <!-- End Batch2 -->
    <logger name="org.hibernate" level="warn">
        <appender-ref ref="BatchALogToFile" />
        <appender-ref ref="BatchBLogToFile" />
    </logger>
    <logger name="org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder" level="trace">
        <appender-ref ref="BatchALogToFile" />
        <appender-ref ref="BatchBLogToFile" />
    </logger>
    <logger name="org.springframework" level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="BatchALogToFile" />
        <appender-ref ref="BatchBLogToFile" />
    </logger>

    <root level="${logback.root.level}">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

I need to attach both appender to hibernate/spring logger in order to receive their logs in a file. The problem is when i do this , even if i don't run the BatchB , the BatchB log file created will receive the hibernate/spring log from the BatchA.
How can i avoid this and fill the batch log file only when i run the associated batch?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by adding hibernate and spring log programmatically

```
public static void addHibernateAndSpringLogs(String loggerName, String appenderName) {
        LoggerContext context = (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
        Appender<ILoggingEvent> saveLogToFile = null;
        for (ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger logger : context.getLoggerList()) {
            if (logger.getName()
                      .equals(loggerName)) {
                for (Iterator<Appender<ILoggingEvent>> index = logger.iteratorForAppenders(); index.hasNext();) {
                    Appender<ILoggingEvent> appender = index.next();
                    if (appender.getName()
                                .equals(appenderName)) {
                        saveLogToFile = appender;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (logger.getName()
                      .startsWith(HIBERNATE_LOGGER)
                    || logger.getName()
                             .startsWith(SPRING_LOGGER)) {
                logger.addAppender(saveLogToFile);

            }

        }
    }
```